# Load and edit PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I would like to know if it is possible to load a PDF and edit it.

The PDF is a brochure with few pages, i would like to put in few images from my database and save it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can import pages of an existing PDF document with [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/). After that you can place the images on top of them with the standard [Image()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm) method of [FPDF](http://fpdf.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Editing a PDF is very difficult programmatically, especially if it wasn't programmatically generated.

A better option would be to make your source file an HTML file, then make your edits to the HTML and convert it to PDF.

Comment: Thank you. Ok do you think if is it possible to transform an HTML and CSS page to PDF. Its very important to keep the structure of my brochure.

Comment: See answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: Editing a PDF is indeed very difficult programmatically. However, the advice to go from PDF to HTML is rather questionable, because it is very difficult to do a proper representation of the contents (and get that back to PDF); if it is nearly possible depends a lot on the input file.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time task, it would be easiest to open the document in Acrobat (Pro), and exchange the images using the Edit text and Images tool.

Another way with Acrobat would be creating a Button form field over the image to be replaced (transparent border, transparent background, no action). Then you import the new image as icon, and flatten the page afterwards.